# Complex JSON Saved to Localstorage Parsed Out To (& Updated From) HTML

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I have a reasonably complex, nested JSON object being sent via AJAX and saved to localstorage. Here's a representative sample:

```
{
"main": [
    {
        "Key1": "alphanum01",
        "Key2": "alphanum02",
        "Key3": "alphanum03",
        "Array1": [
            {
                "Name": "3P",
                "Id": "225954"
            }
        ],
        "Array2": [
            {
                "Name": "1P",
                "Id": "225956"
            }
        ],
        "Array3": [
            {
                "Name": "4P",
                "Id": "225959"
            }
        ],
        "AI1Info": [
            {
                "225954_Key01": "4",
                "225954_Key02": "387",
                "225954_Key03": "23",
                "225954_Key04": "31",
                "225954_Key05": "-4",
                "225954_Key06": "-4",
                "225954_Key07": "-40"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Using jQuery's `$.ajax` functionality I can blob out the "main" array into a localstorage string like so:

```
for(var key in data){
   localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data[key]));
}
```

This is how the data is meant to be sent back to the web service that AJAX-ed it over, so this is fine. However, trying to get the localstorage string back into a traversable state  -- and, just as importantly, being able to update values from an HTML form this localstorage data would initially populate and ultimately be updated from -- is proving challenging. Something simple like:

```
var stuff = localStorage.getItem("main");
var testparse = $.parseJSON(stuff);
console.log(testparse);
```

will only return `[Object]`, while `stuff` simply returns a big string without associated arrays and/or objects. Ideally and as suggested, I'm trying to loop through nested array values to an HTML form via an `$.each` loop, e.g.:

```
var stuff = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("main"));
$.each(stuff."Array"[i], function(i,item){
  $( "[name$='" + item.name + "']" ).val( item.value );
});
```

without success. I am also trying to get that data updated from the form in question. Something like this does seem to work fine in a standalone situation:

```
$( ".saveform" ).click(function( event ) {
var newData1 = $('#form_x').serializeArray();
localStorage.setItem('main', JSON.stringify(newData1));
});
```

But getting the initial population of that form from `main` in localstorage isn't happening.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions or directions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you set at localStorage as

```
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data[key]));
```

and get that value using

```
localStorage.getItem("main");
```

Instead of that use

```
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: `main` is the keyname of the only array available in the for loop for the JSON sample I provided above. Using `key` as the parameter for `localStorage.getItem` won't work because nothing is named "key". And if I changed the main array's keyname from `main` to `key`, I have the same issue.